# How to plot additional points on the top of scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have panda dataframe as df with two attributes df.one (=x) and df.two (=y). Now, I want to plot scatter plot for these data points. I used

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(df.one,df.two,c = 'g',marker = 'o',alpha = 0.2)
```

Now, I want to plot centroid of the data points give by C. How should I overlay centroid on the above scatter plot? 
I tried:

```
ax1.scatter(C[:,0],C[:,1],c = 'r',marker = 'x')
```

But it overrides the scatter plot, I want to overlay on that. Is there any hold on option, similar to `matlab`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need points overlaid on the original plot, use

```
ax.plot(x, y)
```

ex.

```
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.scatter([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
ax.plot(1.5, 1.5, "or")
```

[image]

if you pass a list to x and y, multiple points can be added to the plot. Also in case you need to add some annotation beside the point, try

```
ax.annotate("Some explanation", x, y)
```

Comment: `ax.plot(x,y)` is also overriding my scatter plot.

Comment: That's wired, on my laptop it works fine. I've put up the result.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using? Try to add ´ax.hold()´ just before ´ax.plot(x,y)´

Comment: @Ding - Yes `ax.plot()` worked, it was some other issue as well, which I caught now. Thanks!

Comment: Using custom hash function with HAProxy LoadBalancer

Answer (score 3):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from statistics import *

bill = [34.00, 108.00, 64.00, 88.00, 99.00, 51.00]
tip = [ 5.00,  17.00,  11.00, 8.00,  14.00, 5.00]

bill.sort()
tip.sort()

print(mean(bill))
print(mean(tip))
plt.scatter(bill, tip)
plt.scatter([mean(bill)], [mean(tip)])
plt.show()
```

I wanted to plot the mean of the data too, so I used this format and got this result:

[Result of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2RLP.png)

Comment: But is it possible to plot the points after showing the plot?